# How to move Data grid location if not enough distance from bottom in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have Textbox in which when user types I opens Datagrid if Textbox is at bottom and when user types and obtained Datagrid has Atleast 6 rows then Datargid must move above the Textbox
Following is my code

```
 Point p = Mouse.GetPosition(textBox);
                Point position = textBox.TransformToAncestor(this).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
                ItemsGrid.Margin = new Thickness(position.X - 7, position.Y + 17, 0, 0);
                //also set the height so there isn't empty space.
                ItemsGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                ItemsGrid.Height = ActualHeight - 17 - position.Y;
                double height = ItemsGrid.ColumnHeaderHeight + ((ItemsGrid.Items.Count) * ItemsGrid.RowHeight) + 3;
                if (ItemsGrid.ActualHeight > height || ItemsGrid.Height > height)
                    ItemsGrid.Height = height;
                double isEnoughSpacebtm = ItemsGrid.ColumnHeaderHeight + (6 * ItemsGrid.RowHeight) + 3;
                if (position.Y < isEnoughSpacebtm)
                {
                    ItemsGrid.Margin = new Thickness(position.X - 7, position.Y - 50, 0, 0);
                }
```

I am confused how to achieve this.
please help